# Wildcard constraints scope not used by modules

Tags: snakemake

I have a pipeline that are combining multiple snakemake pipelines using snakemake modules and I have a question about wildcard constrains scope. Let say the pipelines I include, themselves have wildcard constraints definitions:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    barcode="[A-Z+]+",
    chr="[^_]+",
```

Is it possible to override these already defined constraints? I have defined wildcard_constrains in my new pipeline but they doesn't seem to progate into the included modules.